# SQL Count by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

I have a table that has sign ups and the date they signed up. I want to run a query that gives the output of total signups per day.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(dtm_SignUpDate) as TotalSignUpsPerDay, dtm_SignUpDate as Count_Date
FROM tbl_Account
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dtm_SignUpDate))
```

but get

> Column 'tbl_Account.dtm_SignUpDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

what do I need to change to get this to work.

I followed this link ([SQL Count for each date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808611/sql-count-for-each-date)) but it still came up with the same error as described above.

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag the DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle PostgreSQL, ...). Which are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the truncated date in your select clause as-is, it is already a date with hour/minute/seconds removed:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(dtm_SignUpDate) AS TotalSignUpsPerDay,
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dtm_SignUpDate)) AS Count_Date
FROM tbl_Account
GROUP BY
    DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dtm_SignUpDate))
```

PS: people stopped using `DATEADD(dd, 0, ...)` for truncating dates long time ago. You can simply use `CAST(DateTimeVal AS DATE)`.

Comment: Re the Cast element if I amend the SELECT statement to Cast(dtm_SignUpDate AS DATE) as Count_Date then it gives an error as per the original post

Comment: Change it in both places... SELECT and GROUP BY. That is what the error is telling you.

Comment: sorted

SELECT  COUNT(dtm_SignUpDate) AS TotalSignUpsPerDay, Cast(dtm_SignUpDate AS DATE) as Count_Date
FROM tbl_Account
GROUP BY   Cast(dtm_SignUpDate AS DATE)

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
SELECT cast(dtm_SignUpDate as date) as dtm_SignUpDate, count(*) as TotalSignUpsPerDay
FROM tbl_Account
GROUP BY cast(dtm_SignUpDate as date)
ORDER BY cast(dtm_SignUpDate as date);
```

If `dtmSignUpDate` is already a date with no time component, then:

```
SELECT dtm_SignUpDate, count(*) as TotalSignUpsPerDay
FROM tbl_Account
GROUP BY dtm_SignUpDate
ORDER BY dtm_SignUpDate ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, nearly works perfectly - just outputs a column with no name

Comment: @PaulHopkinson . . . Just give the column an alias.